# Spark dataframe seems to be recomputed twice

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, hive, apache-spark-sql

***SOLVED***: I solved the issue, that was due to a very stupid, silly, idiotic mistake in one of the first passages of the flow.
Basically, I was computing a dataframe that was written to a Hive table; this dataframe then needed to be used to create the `temporaryDF` after many passages, but I was originally querying the table from scratch instead of using a copy of the dataframe to-be-written in the table. The mistake lies in the fact that the just-computed dataframes was missing previous partitions (due to the specific logic of the flow), whereas next computations to create `temporaryDF` needed also at least two previous partitions. I don't know why, I can't remember when, I decided to cache the just-computed one, thus losing information and getting an empty one under Oozie (in Spark-Shell I was always using at least three partitions, due to manually updating the table after some time - each new partition came every 15min).  I was probably in a late night working sprint and my brain decided it was worthy to mess it up.

I upvoted and accepted @thebluephantom answer because he is very right within the specific circumstance I was describing.

**Original:**
I'm having a strange behaviour using `Spark-Submit` with Spark v.2.2.0.2.6.4.105-1 (using Scala) in Hadoop 2 under an Oozie workflow vs using `Spark-Shell`.

I have a Hive table that contains records that keep track of some processes every 15 minutes. The table is overwritten every time with new records or 'old' records that still satisfy the logic of the processes of interest.

I keep track of 'the age' of the records through a column that I will here call `times_investigated`, which ranges from 1 to 9.

I create a temporary dataframe, let's call it `temporayDF`, that contains both the old and the new entries (both the types need to be present to run useful computations). This `temporayDF` is then split between the new entries and the old ones, based on `$"times_investigated" === 1` and `$"times_investigated > 1"` (or `=!= 1`).
Then, the processed entries are merged with a `union` in a final dataframe that is then written into the original Hive table.

```scala
// Before, I run the query on the 'old' Hive table and the logic over old and new entries.
// I now have a temporary dataframe
val temporaryDF = previousOtherDF
                  .withColumn("original_col_new", conditions)
                  .withColumn("original_other_col_new", otherConditions)
                  .withColumn("times_investigated_new", nvl($"times_investigated" + 1, 1))
                  .select(
                    previousColumns,
                    $"original_col_new".as("original_col"),
                    $"original_other_col_new".as("original_other_col"),
                    $"times_investigated_new".as("times_investigated"))
                    .cache
                  
                  

// Now I need to split the temporayDF in 2 to run some other logic on the new entries.
val newEntriesDF = temporaryDF
                    .filter($"times_investigated" === 1)
                    .join(neededDF, conditions, "leftouter")
                    .join(otherNeededDF, conditions, "leftouter")
                    .groupBy(cols)
                    .agg(min(colOne),
                         max(colTwo),
                         min(colThree),
                         max(colFour))
                    .withColumn("original_col_five_new",
                                when(conditions).otherwise(somethingElse))
                    .withColumn("original_col_six_new",
                                when(conditions).otherwise(somethingElse)) 
                    .select(orderedColumns)
                    

val oldEntriesDF = temporaryDF.filter($"times_investigated" > 1)

val finalTableDF = oldEntriesDF.union(newEntriesDF)

// Now I write the table
finalTableDF.createOrReplaceTempView(tempFinalTableDF)
sql("""INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE  $finalTableDF 
       SELECT * FROM  tempFinalTableDF """)

// I would then need to re-use the newly-computed table to process further information...
```

The Problem:
The Hive table does not present the new entries with `times_investigated` = 1. It just processes the old ones, so, after those 9 times an entry can stay inside the table, it gets completely empty.

I run some tests within Spark-Shell and everything worked perfectly for many iterations, even manually writing the Hive table from the shell produced the expected results in the Hive table, but when I launched the workflow under Oozie, the strange behavior appeared again.

What I noticed within Spark-Shell is that, after writing the Hive table, if I went to compute a `temporaryDF.show()`, the new entries would be updated to `$"times_investigated"` = 2!

I tried to create a copy of `temporaryDF` to work on separate dataframes with the new and the old entries, but also this `copyOfTemporaryDF` gets updated after writing the Hive table.

It seems that this re-computation is happening before writing the Hive table under Oozie.

I know that I can compute the operations in a different manner, but I need to find a quick temporary fix on the current flow if possible.

Above all, I would love to understand what is happening under the hood, in order to avoid getting myself in such a circumstance later on.

Do you guys have any clue and/or advice?

I tried caching the intermediate dataframes, but without success.

P.S. Sorry for the probably bad coding practices

**EDIT.** More context: the `temporaryDF` comes from other intermediate dataframes, used just once to compute this on of interest. The last passages that create `temporaryDF` are `withColumn` operations, where `$"times_investigated"` is updated with a custom `nvl` function (that works exactly like the SQL one) and never gave problems in older versions of the flow (see below for the passages).

**Edit2:** I also tried to merge the operations on new and old entries in one long chained series, so that `temopraryDF` is actually the final dataframe to be written in the Hive table, but the new entries with `times_investigated` = 1 are still not considered (yet I have no issues via `Spark-Shell` and `.show`ing the dataframe after writing to table makes it re-compute, so the times investigated are +1).

Comment: Question a little hard to follow at a distance.

Comment: What does oozie have to do with it? Just a scheduler?

Comment: I gave context and at last referred to the flow under Oozie to state that it happens when I don't have control of each operation.

Comment: I am going to re-read this tonight, something not adding up. We may need to go to chat at some stage this week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use .cache otherwise you will get re-computation. You should do this for the appropriate dataframe or RDD if the RDD or DF is to be used multiple times in a single Spark App - not even Action dependent, sometimes you get "skipped stages".

```
val temporaryDF = previousOperations...cache()
```

2 vals use temporaryDF and without caching the recomputations will be as you see, and they may well give different results. That should be cached.

Of course if a Worker dies, or the partition evicted, some recomputing is needed.

.cache may not be ideal for datasets larger than available cluster memory. Each partition that is evicted will  be rebuilt from source and that is a costly affair.

Also, using suitable partitioning and iterating a few times be better than persisting / caching; but it all depends.

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to mention that I tried caching, but id didn't seem to work.
I will try again and let you know.

Comment: seem is not a good scientific approach, can you post the .explain pls and state source and show more code?

Comment: Sorry, polite semantics: didn't work. I will provide the .explain in private later, it is pretty long.

Comment: without extra code or an .explain hard to comment; odd

Comment: Hi @thebluephantom, I added more code and some other explanation.